# Cmake: The following tests FAILED

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, debian, ctest

thanks in advance for help.

I need to compile and Debian package cmake 3.24 on Debian buster for debugging purposes.

The compilation runs smoothly, but the testing fails with these results:

```
The following tests FAILED:
152 - CPackComponentsDEB-components-depend2 (Failed)
349 - RunCMake.CMP0019 (Failed)
350 - RunCMake.CMP0022 (Failed)
351 - RunCMake.CMP0026 (Failed)
353 - RunCMake.CMP0037 (Failed)
354 - RunCMake.CMP0038 (Failed)
355 - RunCMake.CMP0039 (Failed)
356 - RunCMake.CMP0040 (Failed)
357 - RunCMake.CMP0041 (Failed)
358 - RunCMake.CMP0043 (Failed)
359 - RunCMake.CMP0045 (Failed)
360 - RunCMake.CMP0046 (Failed)
361 - RunCMake.CMP0049 (Failed)
362 - RunCMake.CMP0050 (Failed)
363 - RunCMake.CMP0051 (Failed)
364 - RunCMake.CMP0053 (Failed)
365 - RunCMake.CMP0054 (Failed)
366 - RunCMake.CMP0055 (Failed)
367 - RunCMake.CMP0057 (Failed)
368 - RunCMake.CMP0059 (Failed)
369 - RunCMake.CMP0060 (Failed)
370 - RunCMake.CMP0064 (Failed)
371 - RunCMake.CMP0069 (Failed)
372 - RunCMake.CMP0081 (Failed)
374 - RunCMake.CMP0106 (Failed)
375 - RunCMake.CMP0111 (Failed)
376 - RunCMake.CMP0115 (Failed)
377 - RunCMake.CMP0118 (Failed)
379 - RunCMake.CMP0121 (Failed)
380 - RunCMake.CMP0125 (Failed)
383 - RunCMake.CMP0135 (Failed)
384 - RunCMake.CMP0139 (Failed)
389 - RunCMake.ABI (Failed)
391 - RunCMake.AutogenQt5 (Failed)
393 - RunCMake.BuildDepends (Failed)
395 - RunCMake.CMakeDependentOption (Failed)
399 - RunCMake.CompilerChange (Failed)
400 - RunCMake.CompilerNotFound (Failed)
401 - RunCMake.Configure (Failed)
402 - RunCMake.DisallowedCommands (Failed)
406 - RunCMake.ExternalData (Failed)
408 - RunCMake.FPHSA (Failed)
409 - RunCMake.FileAPI (Failed)
410 - RunCMake.FindBoost (Failed)
412 - RunCMake.FindOpenGL (Failed)
417 - RunCMake.GenEx-LINK_LANGUAGE (Failed)
418 - RunCMake.GenEx-LINK_LANG_AND_ID (Failed)
421 - RunCMake.GenEx-LINK_LIBRARY (Failed)
422 - RunCMake.GenEx-LINK_GROUP (Failed)
423 - RunCMake.GenEx-TARGET_FILE (Failed)
424 - RunCMake.GenEx-GENEX_EVAL (Failed)
427 - RunCMake.GenEx-PATH_EQUAL (Failed)
428 - RunCMake.GeneratorExpression (Failed)
429 - RunCMake.GeneratorInstance (Failed)
430 - RunCMake.GeneratorPlatform (Failed)
431 - RunCMake.GeneratorToolset (Failed)
432 - RunCMake.GetPrerequisites (Failed)
433 - RunCMake.GNUInstallDirs (Failed)
436 - RunCMake.TargetPropertyGeneratorExpressions (Failed)
437 - RunCMake.Languages (Failed)
438 - RunCMake.LinkItemValidation (Failed)
440 - RunCMake.ObjectLibrary (Failed)
443 - RunCMake.RuntimePath (Failed)
445 - RunCMake.Swift (Failed)
446 - RunCMake.TargetObjects (Failed)
447 - RunCMake.TargetProperties (Failed)
448 - RunCMake.ToolchainFile (Failed)
450 - RunCMake.CompileDefinitions (Failed)
452 - RunCMake.CompileFeatures (Failed)
454 - RunCMake.PolicyScope (Failed)
456 - RunCMake.WriteCompilerDetectionHeader (Failed)
459 - RunCMake.VisibilityPreset (Failed)
460 - RunCMake.CompatibleInterface (Failed)
461 - RunCMake.Syntax (Failed)
463 - RunCMake.MaxRecursionDepth (Failed)
464 - RunCMake.add_custom_command (Failed)
465 - RunCMake.add_custom_target (Failed)
467 - RunCMake.add_executable (Failed)
468 - RunCMake.add_library (Failed)
469 - RunCMake.add_subdirectory (Failed)
471 - RunCMake.build_command (Failed)
472 - RunCMake.execute_process (Failed)
473 - RunCMake.export (Failed)
474 - RunCMake.cmake_host_system_information (Failed)
475 - RunCMake.cmake_language (Failed)
476 - RunCMake.cmake_minimum_required (Failed)
477 - RunCMake.cmake_parse_arguments (Failed)
493 - RunCMake.define_property (Failed)
494 - RunCMake.file (Failed)
496 - RunCMake.file-RPATH (Failed)
498 - RunCMake.find_library (Failed)
499 - RunCMake.find_package (Failed)
501 - RunCMake.find_program (Failed)
502 - RunCMake.foreach (Failed)
504 - RunCMake.get_filename_component (Failed)
505 - RunCMake.get_property (Failed)
506 - RunCMake.if (Failed)
507 - RunCMake.include (Failed)
508 - RunCMake.include_directories (Failed)
510 - RunCMake.list (Failed)
511 - RunCMake.load_cache (Failed)
512 - RunCMake.math (Failed)
513 - RunCMake.message (Failed)
514 - RunCMake.option (Failed)
516 - RunCMake.project (Failed)
517 - RunCMake.project_injected (Failed)
520 - RunCMake.separate_arguments (Failed)
521 - RunCMake.set_property (Failed)
522 - RunCMake.string (Failed)
524 - RunCMake.BundleUtilities (Failed)
525 - RunCMake.try_compile (Failed)
527 - RunCMake.set (Failed)
528 - RunCMake.variable_watch (Failed)
529 - RunCMake.while (Failed)
532 - RunCMake.alias_targets (Failed)
533 - RunCMake.InterfaceLibrary (Failed)
535 - RunCMake.configure_file (Failed)
543 - RunCMake.File_Configure (Failed)
544 - RunCMake.File_Generate (Failed)
545 - RunCMake.ExportWithoutLanguage (Failed)
547 - RunCMake.target_link_libraries (Failed)
551 - RunCMake.target_link_libraries-LINK_LIBRARY (Failed)
552 - RunCMake.target_link_libraries-LINK_GROUP (Failed)
556 - RunCMake.target_compile_features (Failed)
559 - RunCMake.target_sources (Failed)
561 - RunCMake.CheckSourceCompiles (Failed)
562 - RunCMake.CheckSourceRuns (Failed)
563 - RunCMake.CheckModules (Failed)
564 - RunCMake.CheckIPOSupported (Failed)
566 - RunCMake.CommandLine (Failed)
568 - RunCMake.install (Failed)
569 - RunCMake.file-GET_RUNTIME_DEPENDENCIES (Failed)
571 - RunCMake.CPackConfig (Failed)
573 - RunCMake.ExternalProject (Failed)
576 - RunCMake.CTestCommandLine (Failed)
579 - RunCMake.IfacePaths_INCDIRS (Failed)
592 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.CUSTOM_NAMES (Failed)
593 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.DEBUGINFO (Failed)
594 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS (Failed)
595 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.DEPENDENCIES (Failed)
596 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.EMPTY_DIR (Failed)
597 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.VERSION (Failed)
599 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.GENERATE_SHLIBS (Failed)
600 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.GENERATE_SHLIBS_LDCONFIG (Failed)
601 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.LONG_FILENAMES (Failed)
602 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.MINIMAL (Failed)
603 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.PER_COMPONENT_FIELDS (Failed)
604 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.TIMESTAMPS (Failed)
605 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.MD5SUMS (Failed)
606 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.DEB_PACKAGE_VERSION_BACK_COMPATIBILITY (Failed)
607 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.DEB_DESCRIPTION (Failed)
608 - RunCMake.CPack_DEB.PROJECT_META (Failed)
609 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.CUSTOM_BINARY_SPEC_FILE (Failed)
610 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.CUSTOM_NAMES (Failed)
611 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.DEBUGINFO (Failed)
612 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS (Failed)
613 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.DEPENDENCIES (Failed)
614 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.DIST (Failed)
615 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.EMPTY_DIR (Failed)
616 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.VERSION (Failed)
617 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.INSTALL_SCRIPTS (Failed)
618 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.MAIN_COMPONENT (Failed)
619 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.MINIMAL (Failed)
621 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.PER_COMPONENT_FIELDS (Failed)
622 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.SINGLE_DEBUGINFO (Failed)
623 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.EXTRA_SLASH_IN_PATH (Failed)
624 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.SOURCE_PACKAGE (Failed)
625 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.SUGGESTS (Failed)
626 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.SYMLINKS (Failed)
627 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.USER_FILELIST (Failed)
628 - RunCMake.CPack_RPM.PROJECT_META (Failed)
629 - RunCMake.CPack_7Z (Failed)
630 - RunCMake.CPack_TBZ2 (Failed)
631 - RunCMake.CPack_TGZ (Failed)
632 - RunCMake.CPack_TXZ (Failed)
633 - RunCMake.CPack_TZ (Failed)
634 - RunCMake.CPack_ZIP (Failed)
635 - RunCMake.CPack_STGZ (Failed)
636 - RunCMake.CPack_External (Failed)
641 - RunCMake.UnityBuild (Failed)
642 - RunCMake.CMakePresets (Failed)
643 - RunCMake.CMakePresetsBuild (Failed)
645 - RunCMake.VerifyHeaderSets (Failed)
```

The source has been cloned from he debian salsa git repo.

All the pre-requisites are satisfied except for "python3-sphinxcontrib.qthelp" and "dh-sequence-sphinxdoc" which are mainly doc creation helpers, so I think they shouldn't have a big impact.

The question is; is this a normal behavior so I have to skip the testing then enable the failed features like "Policy CMP0139" for example? Or am I missing something?

I'm running the stock 5.10 kernel with the full headers packages, so I don't think any header file is missing, but I can review that if it was a pointer to a solution.

Compiling/packaging the latest kernel shouldn't be a problem, but I need to run on a stock kernel.

Comment: So many fails don't *look* as normal, but it is impossible to be more concrete without viewing **logs** of these tests. Why did you ever run these tests in the first place? If you want to use CMake for your project, then just try to use. If CMake will be able to configure and build your project, then I see no reason to run tests on CMake.

Comment: Thank you for participating ...
The tests are in the Debian script Debian/rules, which is a standard script that has to be passed to the deb-helper tool chain to produce a standard Debian package.
The script and the tests came from the same GIT repo as the cmake source, so these tests are rather standard for the Debian system for cmake to run to confirm functionality of both the package and the OS and avoid further compilation errors for other packages.

You can take a peek here: https://salsa.debian.org/cmake-team/cmake

Comment: I tried to add the full log, but the forum software didn't accept to save the post. I'll work on posting it to a pastebin or something.

Comment: I don't expect the log for a **single** test will be so long.

Comment: @Deyaa did you find a solution to this problem? I am also facing this error. Thanks in advance!